# Do I have to transfer money to a USA bank for the release of a inheritance fund into my bank?

Tags: united-states, scams

My Grandmother from USA gave me all her inheritance. Now in order for me to get the fund in my bank they are asking me to transfer 1000 USD to the bank.

Comment: That STINKS like a scam?

Comment: Who is asking for the $1000? What country are you in? Is this your biological grandmother or someone you only knew online?

Comment: Why does this remind me of the Nigerian 419 scam?

Answer (score 18):

It's a scam. If it really cost $1,000 to get the funds, then the bank would just take it out of the inheritance.

Scam: You inherited $100,000. You pay $1,000 fees. There is no inheritance.

Real inheritance: You inherited $100,000. There's a $1,000 fee. The bank puts $99,000 into your bank account.

Comment: Also, a real inheritance in the US typically wouldn't be handled by a bank.  It would be handled by the executor for the estate, which could be an individual or law firm named in the deceased's will, or a government official - "Public Administrator" in my state.  They are typically paid for their time & expenses from the estate, before it is distributed to the heirs.  (At least in most statess: IANAL, so check on the Law SE site for details.)

Comment: @jamesqf — banks are sometimes named as executors. They have trust departments for that sort of thing. That doesn’t affect the scamminess here.

Answer (score 4):

This is a scam. Stay away. There is no money.